# Accept any HTTP method/verb in ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an action on an `ApiController` in an ASP.NET project.

I want it to accept any HTTP method (even bogus ones, if possible).

I can't find a *Don't filter by method* attribute though.  Do I have to create one?

Adding multiple attributes works fine for the *standard* methods.  Can I catch everything though?

**NB** This is a Framework 4.72 application, not a Core application

Comment: Do you want to accept the methods per controller or per single method in the controller?

Comment: Not sure what do you want to achieve here but, you write a `middleware` and play around with requests.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot ignore filtering by `HTTP` method completely in `Web API`, the framework seems to be pretty strict in this matter. But you can specify predefined set of any method names you need (even bogus ones) using `AcceptVerbs` attribute

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST", "GET", "MyMethod", "Bo-Gus")]
public IHttpActionResult MyAction()
```

Or you can implement `IActionHttpMethodProvider` that returns allowed methods

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class AllowBogusMethodsAttribute : Attribute, IActionHttpMethodProvider
{
    public Collection<HttpMethod> HttpMethods
    {
        get
        {
            return new Collection<HttpMethod>
            {

                HttpMethod.Get,
                HttpMethod.Post,
                new HttpMethod("MyMethod"),
                new HttpMethod("Bo-Gus")
            };

        }
    }
}
```

and use it like this

```
[AllowBogusMethods]
public IHttpActionResult MyAction()
```

**Note**

`HttpMethods` getter will be called only once during application lifetime and its result will be cached, and therefore you cannot add new allowed `HTTP` methods during requests and return updated collection.

Answer (score -3):

If you do not apply any action verb, then that action will be treated as `GET` request action. That is the default behavior.

I never tried with adding HttpGet, `HttpPost`, `Put` etc. to the same action.

Alternative approach would be to have individual actions for different http verbs and then redirect to one action with parameters.